# Can we have more error (messages)?

Tags: r, language-concepts

Is there a way, in R, to pop up an error message if a function uses a variable
not declared in the body of the function: i.e, i want someone to flag this type of functions

```
aha<-function(p){
  return(p+n)
}
```

see; if there happens to be a "n" variable lying somewhere, aha(p=2) will give me an "answer" since R will just take "n" from that mysterious place called the "environment"

Comment: That's usually called a 'feature' :)  It would be the same in C or C++, by the way, with scoping going from the local function to the next layer, usually global.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to detect such potential problems during the code-writing phase and not during run-time, then the `codetools` package is your friend.

```
library(codetools)
aha<-function(p){ 
  return(p+n) 
}

#check a specific function:
checkUsage(aha) 

#check all loaded functions:
checkUsageEnv(.GlobalEnv)
```

These will tell you that `no visible binding for global variable ‘n’`.

Answer (score 5):

Richie's suggestion is very good.

I would just add that you should consider creating unit test cases that would run in a clean R environment.  That will also eliminate the concern about global variables and ensures that your functions behave the way that they should.  You might want to consider using [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/index.html) for this.  I have my test suite scheduled to run every night in a new environment using RScript, and that's very effective and catching any kind of scope issues, etc.

Comment: +1 for clean environment -- that's what I use 'r' from littler for all the time, and there is Rscript if you're on the one platform we don't support for littler.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Writing R codes to check other R code is going to be tricky.  You'd have to find a way to determine which bits of code were variable declarations, and then try and work out whether they'd already been declared within the function.</strike>
EDIT: The previous statement would have been true, but as Aniko pointed out, the hard work has already been done in the [`codetools`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/codetools/index.html) package.

One related thing that may be useful to you is to force a variable to be taken from the function itself (rather than from an enclosing environment).

This modified version of your function will always fail, since `n` is not declared.

```
aha <- function(p) 
{ 
   n <- get("n", inherits=FALSE)
   return(p+n)
}
```